# How to generate random 64-bit value as decimal string in PHP

Tags: php, random, oauth, arbitrary-precision

Oauth requires a random 64-bit, unsigned number encoded as an ASCII string in decimal format. Can you guys help me achieve this with php?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two 32-bit numbers, four 16-bit numbers, etc.

PHP has [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and and [mt_rand()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) but how many random bits they supply isn't specified by the standard (though they can be queried with the help of [getrandmax()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php) and [mt_getrandmax()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php), respectively.)

So your <strike>safest</strike> simplest bet would be generating 64 random bits and setting them one by one.

As for working with 64-bit integers, I'd recommend using the [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) library as it has a good range of functions to help you out.

You could create a number, call 64 [gmp_setbit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-setbit.php)s on it with successive positions then convert it to a string using gmp_strval().

Answer (score 30):

This was a really interesting problem (how to create the decimal representation of an arbitrary-length random number in PHP, using no optional extensions). Here's the solution:

### Step 1: arbitrary-length random number

```
// Counts how many bits are needed to represent $value
function count_bits($value) {
    for($count = 0; $value != 0; $value >>= 1) {
        ++$count;
    }
    return $count;
}

// Returns a base16 random string of at least $bits bits
// Actual bits returned will be a multiple of 4 (1 hex digit)
function random_bits($bits) {
    $result = '';
    $accumulated_bits = 0;
    $total_bits = count_bits(mt_getrandmax());
    $usable_bits = intval($total_bits / 8) * 8;

    while ($accumulated_bits < $bits) {
        $bits_to_add = min($total_bits - $usable_bits, $bits - $accumulated_bits);
        if ($bits_to_add % 4 != 0) {
            // add bits in whole increments of 4
            $bits_to_add += 4 - $bits_to_add % 4;
        }

        // isolate leftmost $bits_to_add from mt_rand() result
        $more_bits = mt_rand() & ((1 << $bits_to_add) - 1);

        // format as hex (this will be safe)
        $format_string = '%0'.($bits_to_add / 4).'x';
        $result .= sprintf($format_string, $more_bits);
        $accumulated_bits += $bits_to_add;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

At this point, calling `random_bits(2048)` will give you 2048 random bits as a hex-encoded string, no problem.

### Step 2: arbitrary-precision base conversion

Math is hard, so here's the code:

```
function base_convert_arbitrary($number, $fromBase, $toBase) {
    $digits = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $length = strlen($number);
    $result = '';

    $nibbles = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $nibbles[$i] = strpos($digits, $number[$i]);
    }

    do {
        $value = 0;
        $newlen = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $value = $value * $fromBase + $nibbles[$i];
            if ($value >= $toBase) {
                $nibbles[$newlen++] = (int)($value / $toBase);
                $value %= $toBase;
            }
            else if ($newlen > 0) {
                $nibbles[$newlen++] = 0;
            }
        }
        $length = $newlen;
        $result = $digits[$value].$result;
    }
    while ($newlen != 0);
    return $result;
}
```

This function will work as advertised, for example try `base_convert_arbitrary('ffffffffffffffff', 16, 10) == '18446744073709551615'` and `base_convert_arbitrary('10000000000000000', 16, 10) == '18446744073709551616'`.

### Putting it together

```
echo base_convert_arbitrary(random_bits(64), 16, 10);
```

Comment: +1 for the mind-blowingness of even *thinking* of doing that in PHP.  Keep in mind that `count_bits` won't be able to deal with numbers larger than PHP_INT_MAX.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the vote. `count_bits` is indeed limited, but as we 're only going to use it to measure the return value of `mt_getrandmax` it's adequate for the job.

Comment: Very adequate considering that `mt_getrandmax` usually seems to be 2^31-1 even on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Just FYI: sometimes number respresentation can contain leading zeros (i.e., result of hash() function), and this function obviously can't restore them after converting. So if `nab = convert(n, a, b)` it can be that `n !== convert(nab, b, a)`. Be careful.

Comment: Interesting function `base_convert_arbitrary`. But why all the alphabets? Doesn't `$value = $value * $fromBase + $nibbles[$i];` ensure that the operation can only be valid for base 2 to 16?

Comment: Interesting, I just noticed what nibbles actually has is `strpos` not `substr`. I'm still confused however at `($value >= $toBase) {
                $nibbles[$newlen++] = (int)($value / $toBase);
                $value %= $toBase;
            }`, what exactly is happening here? Comments would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you building an OAuth adapter yourself?  If so, you might want to reconsider.  There are plenty of good OAuth libraries out there, including [one from PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth), [one in PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/redirected), [another from the Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html), and [this other one hosted on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-for-php/).  I've worked with the first three, and they're all pretty decent.

If you *really* want to do this yourself, you may face an issue.  PHP can't think in 64-bit numbers unless it's compiled on a 64-bit platform or you have an advanced mathematics extension installed.  This is going to make presenting a 64-bit number as a decimal *very* difficult.  It looks like many of the libraries I linked above *completely ignore the format requirement* and simply work with a raw MD5 hash.  Here's the code from ZF's adapter:

```
/**
 * Generate nonce
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function generateNonce()
{
    return md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}
```

They look like they're getting away with this *without* interoperability issues.