# Turning an integer into random string and back again

Tags: php

what I'm wanting is to convert an integer into a string. For example, 123456789 may become 8GFsah93r ... you know like Youtube, Pastebin and what not. I then want to convert it back.

I'm working with large integers, for example: 131569877435989900

Take a look at this link: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wHKOMi

This is my attempt using a function I found on the web, obviously... it's not correctly converting back to integer. I'm needing something that does this realiably.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds pointless.

Comment: Shorter urls... perhaps?

Comment: Is this because you just want to fit the integer into a smaller space, or are you using this as a security measure?

Comment: So cutting down a, say, 20-digit number to a 10-digit string makes a difference for you? It's not going to be hand-type-friendly either way, and copy/paste works just as good with 10 chars more.

Comment: site.com/1234567891234567890123456789 ... gotta admit, it looks pretty awful. I don't care if you think it's pointless, fact is - I want to do it and I need help with it.

Comment: Base36 (A-Z0-9) is the common way used by shorteners; 131569877435989900 -> zzhmn9ztjm8

Comment: OK, it's your app, you call the shots. I 've added an answer that you will hopefully find adequate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, one of the ideas is to use a character array as a **representation of a numeric system**. Then you can convert from **base 10 to base x** and vica-versa. The value will be shorter and less readable (altought, you should **encrypt** it with a two-way crypter if it must be secure).

A solution:

```
final class UrlShortener {

    private static $charfeed = Array(
    'a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','e','E','f','F','g','G','h','H','i','I','j','J','k','K','l','L','m',
    'M','n','N','o','O','p','P','q','Q','r','R','s','S','t','T','u','U','v','V','w','W','x','X','y','Y',
    'z','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

    public static function intToShort($number) {
        $need = count(self::$charfeed);
        $s = '';

        do {
            $s .= self::$charfeed[$number%$need];
            $number = floor($number/$need);
        } while($number > 0);

        return $s;
    }

    public static function shortToInt($string) {
        $num = 0;
        $need = count(self::$charfeed);
        $length = strlen($string);

        for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
            $key = array_search($string[$x], self::$charfeed);
            $value = $key * pow($need, $x);
            $num += $value;
        }

        return $num;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
UrlShortener::intToShort(2);
UrlShortener::shortToInt("b");
```

**EDIT**

with large numbers, it does not work. You should use this version (with bcmath http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php ) with very large numbers:

```
final class UrlShortener {

    private static $charfeed = Array(
    'a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','e','E','f','F','g','G','h','H','i','I','j','J','k','K','l','L','m',
    'M','n','N','o','O','p','P','q','Q','r','R','s','S','t','T','u','U','v','V','w','W','x','X','y','Y',
    'z','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

    public static function intToShort($number) {
        $need = count(self::$charfeed);
        $s = '';

        do {
            $s .= self::$charfeed[bcmod($number, $need)];
            $number = floor($number/$need);
        } while($number > 0);

        return $s;
    }

    public static function shortToInt($string) {
        $num = 0;
        $need = count(self::$charfeed);
        $length = strlen($string);

        for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
            $key = array_search($string[$x], self::$charfeed);
            $value = $key * bcpow($need, $x);
            $num += $value;
        }

        return $num;
    }
}
$original = 131569877435989900;
$short = UrlShortener::intToShort($original);
echo $short;
echo '<br/>';
$result = UrlShortener::shortToInt($short);
echo $result;
echo '<br/>';
echo bccomp($original, $result);
```

If something missing from here, please let me know, because it's only a snippet from my library (I don't wanna insert the whole thing here)

negra

Comment: I like it! http://codepad.viper-7.com/m7GC6U ;) though I don't understand it... *facepalm* - There was a few typos with "ulr" but managed to fix.

Comment: It does throw out some undefined offsets when you have E_NOTICE on though... any way to fix that?

Comment: yep, sorry for the typos, I renamed the class from the original internal name. :)

Comment: Fail... on my xampp: 131569877435989900 turns into AuIOUswE and AuIOUswE turns into 34227335412637 ... ?

Comment: This is the url: http://213.249.184.108/urlshort.php it's pretty much running the same code as on the viper-7 link... -.-

Comment: it seems that these numbers are too big for such operations...thats why the e_notice and the invalid conversion for 131 569 877 435 989 900

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3369/discussion-between-jeanie-tallis-and-pinusnegra)

Comment: @Jeanie edited my answer with a BCMath version (for large numbers) with a test. It seems to work. please check out

Answer (score 2):

check base64 encoding: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

If you want a shorter string first encode it into an 8bit string then encode. You can do this with `% 256` and `/ 256`.

Or you could manually do what base64 does, get the first 6bits and encode it to a char.

Comment: URLs would be too long. Plus, they do have special characters eg: = ... I'm not wanting them.

Comment: I'd replace it with ... nothing. It would be tricky to replace nothing with a =

Comment: Also: http://codepad.viper-7.com/MdEjia converting into 8bit didn't quite work out so nicely.

Comment: lol, you have to do that repeatedly to build an 8bit string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use something like [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) -- unfortunately, it won't work for such large integers correctly.

However, you can use the same idea by copying `base_convert_arbitrary` from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301034/how-to-generate-random-64-bit-value-as-decimal-string/5302533#5302533) and doing:

```
$id = '131569877435989900';
$encoded = base_convert_arbitrary($id, 10, 36);
$decoded = base_convert_arbitrary($encoded, 36, 10);

print_r($encoded);
print_r($decoded);
```

[**See it in action**](http://www.ideone.com/4GBYH).

The nice thing about this approach is that you can tweak the first line inside the function, which reads:

```
$digits = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; // 36 "digits"
```

Add any other "digits" you find acceptable (e.g. capital letters or other symbols you don't mind having in your URL). You can then replace the base `36` in the above example with a larger one (you can go as high as there are defined digits), and it will work just like you want it to.

**[See it here working with 62 digits](http://www.ideone.com/DECfs)**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this? Do you need it heavily encrypted?

```
$num = 131569877435989900;
echo $str = base64_encode($num);
echo base64_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to encode the ids using [Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32). The resulting string contains only the 26 letters of the alphabet and the digits 2-7, making it very human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am suprised No one is mentioning base64_encode() and it partner  base64_decode().
If you were not considering length this is perfect

```
$before = base64_encode(131569877435989900);

$after = 'MS4zMTU2OTg3NzQzNTk5RSsxNw==';

$on_reverse = base64_decode('MS4zMTU2OTg3NzQzNTk5RSsxNw==');
$on_reverse == 131569877435989900;
```

I always go for the simplest solutions, as long as they don't compromise my security.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to get random string is to use hash functions like `md5()` or `sha1()` For example:

```
<?php
$bigInt = '131569877435989900';
$hash = md5($bigInt);
$hashed=substr($hash,0,-20);
echo $hashed;
?>
```

These hash functions are irreversible-you can't get the original value(these functions are also used to crypt data). If you want you can save the original big integer in an array or a database. But decripting the hash would be impossible.

Comment: Getting the first 12 hexadecimal characters off an MD5 string is generally a bad idea, since you hugely increase the chances of collisions.

Comment: It was just an example to show the fastest way of making 'youtube' type hash strings.