# Convert hex to ascii characters

Tags: php, encoding, decoding

Is it possible to represent a sequence of hex characters (0-9A-F) with a sequence of 0-9a-zA-Z characters, so the the result sequence is smaller and can be decoded?

For example:

```
$hex = '5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592';
echo $string = encode($hex); // someASCIIletters123
echo decode(string) == $hex; //true
```

Comment: I think he means cramming 2 (4-byte) hex digits into one byte (which should be possible all right)

Comment: Looks like you just reinvented base64...  Well, base62, but I'd go with the well known and supported everywhere base64 if I were you.

Comment: @Robik. I think zie means turn base 16 to base 62. The higher the base, the shorter the string, so the "result sequence" would indeed be "smaller". The 62 digit characters are 0-9a-zA-Z. Neat notion, but I don't know of any simple way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trivially adapt the solution I presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386790/turning-an-integer-into-random-string-and-back-again/7387282#7387282) using the function `base_convert_arbitrary`.

**Edit:** I had not read carefully enough :) Base 16 to base 62 is still very doable, as above.

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/0ySpo)**.

Comment: this would be better to have a solution that doesn't depend on another solution of yours

Answer (score 30):

I think you're looking for this:

```
function hex2str($hex) {
    $str = '';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=2) $str .= chr(hexdec(substr($hex,$i,2)));
    return $str;
}
```

(From http://www.linux-support.com/cms/php-convert-hex-strings-to-ascii-strings/)
(Works like this javascript tool: http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html)

Answer (score 19):

You mean want to convert a string of hex digits into actual hex values?

```
$hex_string = "A1B2C3D4F5"; // 10 chars/bytes
$packed_string = pack('H*', $hex_string); // 0xA1B2C3D4F5 // 5 chars/bytes.
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in php functions may help some landing here on a search:

```php
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin
$hex = '6578616d706c65206865782064617461';
echo hex2bin($hex); // example hex data
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, something *similar*, yes... parse the hex characters as a binary value, then convert to base64. That uses a *little* bit more than 0-9 a-z A-Z, but only a few more characters. Are you okay to use three other characters in addition to those 62? You can use [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to perform the encoding if so.

(You could convert to base32 instead, but that wouldn't be as compact. Converting to bases which aren't powers of 2 is also feasible, but less appealing.)

You'd also need some way of representing a final half-byte if your input sequence had an odd number of characters. You'll probably want to think about that before calling [`pack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to do the original parsing...

Comment: @fvu: The 65th character is the equals sign, which may appear only at the end of the encoded string. Google the encoding method to see why you need it.

Comment: @jon ahhh, you are referring to the pad character that's mandatory in a number of b64 variants.  He could as well pick eg RFC4648, Nmtoken or Name and save 1 byte

Comment: @fvu: Yes, potentially. The benefit of using a "standard" base64 is that it's more easily portable to other platforms. Usually the difference between needing to find 64 characters and needing to find 65 isn't significant.

Comment: @fvu: However, `base64_encode` is built into PHP and lots of other languages, which pretty much dictates what any of us would pick.