# ASCII characters returned null NSJSONSerialization

Tags: php, objective-c, ios

I have data stored in mysql database, the data is encoded in ascii because of some special characters, i am trying to fetch data for iphone application, the json format is correct but due to special characters it returned me null
    42756666616c6f205068696c6c79e28099732077696e67732c20636865657365737465616b7320616e64206d6f7265
this is stored in mysql table while actually it is **Buffalo Philly’s wings, cheesesteaks and more**
i tried with html_entity_decode, html2text but none help me, please help on this i am really stucked.

here is the code how i fetch data from db and print it in json format:

```
$sql = "SELECT  p.product_id,p.image,p.model,d.name,d.product_id,d.language_id  FROM product AS p ,product_description AS d

        WHERE 
        d.product_id = p.product_id
        AND
        d.language_id = 1

        ORDER BY p.date_added


        limit 10
    ";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();
$products = '{"products":{';
$num = mysql_num_rows($rs);

while($d = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($path.$d['image']);
$image->resize(55,55);
$img = strtotime("now").$count;
$image->save("images/".$img.'.jpg');
$pimage = "$img_url/$img.jpg";

$name = html_entity_decode($d['name'],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


$highlight = html_entity_decode($d['model'],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


if($count < $num){
    $products .= '"'.$d["product_id"].'":[
                                            {
                                                "id":"'.$d["product_id"].'",
                                                "name":"'.$name.'",
                                                "image_url":"'.$pimage.'",
                                                "highlight":"'.$highlight.'"
                                            }
                                        ],';
    }else{
    $products .= '"'.$d["product_id"].'":[
                                            {
                                                "id":"'.$d["product_id"].'",
                                                "name":"'.$d["name"].'",
                                                "image_url":"'.$pimage.'",
                                                "highlight":"'.$highlight.'"
                                            }
                                        ]';
}

}
$products .='}}';

print($products);
```

Object-c code is:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soURL];
    NSError *error;
    productsRaw = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    products = [productsRaw objectForKey:@"products"];
    productKeys = [products allKeys];
```

Comment: Post your code. How are you fetching data?

Comment: @Kreiri i have edited the question with php code to fetch data from db

Comment: he meant the objC code I guess...

Comment: both codes php and objective c is added to question

Comment: but there is no issue with objective C code because it fetch all those items which have no special characters, but when even a single item with special character appears then it return `null`

Answer (score 0):

That string seems to be hex encoded. 
You can use the [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function, like below:

```
pack('H*', $data);
```

as explained in [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488538/convert-hex-to-ascii-characters), or something close to it (the `'h*'` packing parameter may work).

Beware that the resulting string will be **locale** encoded, so depending on which locales were used in the original application, you may have to do some locale conversion to get a properly encoded string. For that purpose, I suggest the use of the [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function, but at any rate you have to know the originally used locale.