# Converting '0x3132333435' to '12345' in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, hex

I was trying to recover some password data on my SQL SERVER 2012 files, unfortunately I forgot what encryption was used in encoding the password to the tables. I know that `0x3132333435` translates as `12345`, as this was my test account before.

I tried to use `hexdec()` but no luck, there seems to be a pattern with the structure of the password. `0x3132333435` translates as `0x3(1)3(2)3(3)3(4)3(5)` with the data 12345 being 'sandwiched' between hex 0x3 and 3's.

This is one of my code's part.

```
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Cannot find account with the username';
        } else {
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (hexdec($password, $row['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['id'];
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
            }
        }
```

I've read some of the topics about this as well, but I don't have any idea on how to implement it:

> Currently, classes "wep" and "wpa" are suported. The WEP
>   (Wired  Equivalent  Privacy)  key  can be either 5 or 13
>   bytes long. It can be provided either  as  an  ASCII  or
>   hexadecimal  string  --  thus "12345" and "0x3132333435"
>   are equivalent 5-byte keys (the "0x" prefix may be omit-
>   ted). A file containing a WEP key must consist of a sin-
>   gle line using either WEP key format.   The  WPA  (Wi-Fi
>   Protected  Access)  key  must  be  provided  as an ASCII
>   string with a length between 8 and 63 bytes.

Is it possible to do it manually? Or is there some link that I can use as a guide or reference?

I am trying to use the old table (user's masterfile) so that my old users can still access the system. I'm currently using `hash()` for my new password table.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486625/924299) might be helpful. It seems to use `hexdec()` to convert hex pairs to decimal and then `chr()` to convert the resulting number to ascii.

Comment: @showdev I completely forgot, it was nested. ````(chr(hexdec($password, $row['password'])))```` worked like charm! thank you for the link, it saved me.