# Auto-generate Base62 numbers without vowels (PHP)?

Tags: php, base62

This may end up being a trivial question - I know I'm going to need to do this soon for an app I'm working on, but haven't really worked on it myself yet - I'm really just floating it to see if there's an obvious method I'm missing.

Basically, what I need is to generate a sequence of numbers using a-z, A-Z, 0-9, except without vowels.  There is a small chance I will need to make it unpredictable, so being able to generate out of order is a bonus.

I'm initially thinking for each new one to just work forward from the last no-vowel match until I find the next one (or generate random numbers until I get one I don't have already in the case of unpredictable values), but is there a better way?  Perhaps a baseX number system obj that allows you to specify the allowable characters?

Using PHP/MySQL if it matters.

Comment: I haven't really worked on my answer yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function in an answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301034/how-to-generate-random-64-bit-value-as-decimal-string/5302533#5302533) that can convert from any base to any other and which lets you customize the digit pool; it also works on arbitrary-sized input. You can generate a sequence in base 10 and convert to whatever you need.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!  I'll be tweaking it and making it part of my core id generator =o)