# convert string generated from Number.toString to number

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion

I use `Number.toString` method to convert numbers to string.

```
Number(100).toString(16);
Number(1000).toString(36);
```

How can I convert them back to the original numbers?

Comment: I’m sure this is a duplicate of something…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337419 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258828 already have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
parseInt(Number(100).toString(16), 16);
parseInt(Number(1000).toString(36), 36);
```

Comment: I feel really stupid since I've already tried `parseInt` with radix `10`. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Number("10") === 10
```

You can pass any string into Number and it will turn it into a number object. I prefer this method since if it contains any non-number characters, it will resolve to `NaN` which is what you want most of the time.

If you're parsing a string which *begins with a number* but may contain alpha characters afterwards, `parseInt` and `parseFloat` both will parse the leading numerics out - but you can forget about any numbers which may be mixed into the string elsewhere.