# php curl certificate: curlopt_certinfo: where is serial number hiding?

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate

Curl and the output: can't find the serial number of the certificate.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.comodo.com/');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);



curl_exec($curl);

$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
$certs = $info["certinfo"];
?> <pre><?php echo var_dump($certs) ?></pre>
```

where is the certificate serial number hiding? can't find it
in this example answer should be: 
    26:32:AC:57:23:86:91:BB:D5:88:D3:D8:E9:DA:0B:4E

note: other variables of the certificate are retrieved, except doesn't look like it includes certificate serial number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get SSL certificate info with CURL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081042/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-info-with-curl-in-php)

Comment: @Stony: I think the question was straightforward, cert_info does not appear to retrieve serial number of certificate. is that clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution. Curl provides access to the original Base64-encoded certificate,
so you can parse it using [`openssl_x509_parse()`](http://php.net/openssl_x509_parse)
to obtain the serial number as an integer string:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.comodo.com/');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_exec($curl);

$certInfo   = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CERTINFO);
$rawCert    = $certInfo[0]['Cert'];
$parsedCert = openssl_x509_parse($rawCert);
$serialNum  = $parsedCert['serialNumber'];

var_dump($serialNum);
```

This will output:

```
string(38) "50773774161050170991724859325180152654"
```

This is too large for [`dechex()`](http://php.net/dechex) to convert to hex.
Instead, you could use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540041)
which requires the [BCMath](http://php.net/book.bc) extension:

```
function bcdechex($dec)
{
    $hex = '';
    do {
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last) . $hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while ($dec > 0);
    return $hex;
}

$serialNumHex = bcdechex($serialNum);
$serialNumHex = chunk_split($serialNumHex, 2, ':');
$serialNumHex = trim($serialNumHex, ':');

var_dump($serialNumHex);
```

This will output:

```
string(47) "26:32:ac:57:23:86:91:bb:d5:88:d3:d8:e9:da:0b:4e"
```