# php convert decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: php

I am extracting a serial from a digital certificate using the built-in OpenSSL library, however, I am having trouble converting this number to hex with precision.

The extracted number is originally in decimal but I need to have it in hex.

The number I am trying to convert is: 114483222461061018757513232564608398004

Here is what I've tried:

- `dechex()` did not work, it returns: `7fffffffffffffff`

The closest I could get was this function from the [php.net](https://www.php.net/dechex) page but it does not convert the whole number on part of it.

```
function dec2hex($dec) {
  $hex = ($dec == 0 ? '0' : '');

  while ($dec > 0) {
    $hex = dechex($dec - floor($dec / 16) * 16) . $hex;
    $dec = floor($dec / 16);
  }

  return $hex;
}
echo dec2hex('114483222461061018757513232564608398004');
//Result: 5620aaa80d50fc000000000000000000
```

Here is what I am expecting:

- Decimal number: 114483222461061018757513232564608398004
- Expected hex: 5620AAA80D50FD70496983E2A39972B4

I can see the correction conversion here:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

I need a PHP solution.

Comment: How do you obtain the number? Are you able to obtain it as a string (without casting)?

Comment: here is the digital cert: http://pastebin.com/34Tgs6Lw

`$cert = openssl_x509_parse($certdata);` then `echo $cert['serialNumber'];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is [that `The largest number that can be converted is ...  4294967295`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php#refsect1-function.dechex-description) - hence why it's not working for you.

[This answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php#21086) worked for me during a quick test, assuming you have bcmath installed on your server, **and you can obtain the number as a string to start with**. If you can't, i.e. it begins life as numeric variable, you'll immediately reach [PHP's float limit](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

```
// Credit: joost at bingopaleis dot com
// Input: A decimal number as a String.
// Output: The equivalent hexadecimal number as a String.
function dec2hex($number)
{
    $hexvalues = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
               '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');
    $hexval = '';
     while($number != '0')
     {
        $hexval = $hexvalues[bcmod($number,'16')].$hexval;
        $number = bcdiv($number,'16',0);
    }
    return $hexval;
}
```

Example:

```
$number = '114483222461061018757513232564608398004'; // Important: already a string!
var_dump(dec2hex($number)); // string(32) "5620AAA80D50FD70496983E2A39972B4"
```

Ensure you pass a string into that function, not a numeric variable. In the example you provided in the question, it looks like you can obtain the number as a string initially, so should work if you have bc installed.

Comment: after installing bcmatch and restarting apache it works. Restarting apache must be done.

Answer (score 5):

This is a big integer, so you need to use a big-integer library like [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php):

```
echo gmp_strval('114483222461061018757513232564608398004', 16);
// output: 5620aaa80d50fd70496983e2a39972b4
```

Comment: Does this example work if the input is not a string?

Comment: got this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gmp_strval() in /var/www/html/index.php Stack trace: #0 {main}`

Comment: @RobbieAverill: What is the input if it is not a string? PHP's integer is 32- or 64-bit long, but OP's number is 128-bit.

Comment: Exactly :) but nevermind, he can obtain it as a string.

Comment: @user3436467: Looks like your PHP [isn't compiled with GMP support](http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php) then.

Answer (score 5):

Answered by lafor.
[How to convert a huge integer to hex in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539727/how-to-convert-a-huge-integer-to-hex-in-php)

```
function bcdechex($dec) 
{
    $hex = '';
    do {    
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last).$hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while($dec>0);
    return $hex;
}

Example:
$decimal = '114483222461061018757513232564608398004';
echo "Hex decimal : ".bcdechex($decimal);
```

Comment: i remember seeing this before posting but it didnt work for me at the time.. I just installed bcmath and restarted apache and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this 100% working for any number

```
 <?php 
        $dec = '114483222461061018757513232564608398004';
     // init hex array
       $hex = array();
       while ($dec)
       {
         // get modulus // based on docs both params are string
          $modulus = bcmod($dec, '16');
          // convert to hex and prepend to array
          array_unshift($hex, dechex($modulus));
         // update decimal number
         $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $modulus), 16);
        }
       // array elements to string
       echo implode('', $hex);

?>
```