# Convert number to and from alphanumeric code

Tags: php

Is it possible to convert from numeric to an alphanumeric code like this:

```
a
b
c
d
..
z
1
2
3
4
..
aa
ab
ac
ad
..
az
a1
a2
a3
a4
..
aaa
aab
aac
aad
..
aaz
aa1
aa2
```

etc.

I'm trying to convert large numbers to smaller length alphanumeric strings.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Of course it is possible. If you can describe the conversion, you can code it.

Comment: what are the possibilities between 4 and aa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know why you want to do this specifically, but try changing the base from 10 to something like 32;

```
 base_convert($number, 10, 32);
```

Then to convert back

```
 base_convert($number, 32, 10);
```

As someone else pointed out - for very large numbers this may not work.

If you need to be able to handle very large numbers, check out this link:

[How to generate random 64-bit value as decimal string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301034/how-to-generate-random-64-bit-value-as-decimal-string-in-php/5302533#5302533)

Comment: Thank you, what I want is actually base 36 i.e. the whole alphabet then 1-9.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `base_convert()` for changing the base of your number from 10 (decimal) to 36 (26 latin letters plus 10 arabic numerals).

The result will differ from your given example list. You have used the digits `abc..xyz012..789`, `base_convert` will use a diffent order `012..789abc..xyz`.

```
// convert decimal to base36
echo base_convert($number_dec, 10 , 36);

// convert base36 to decimal
echo base_convert($number_b36, 36 , 10);
```

Translation

```
dec     base36
0       0
1       1
...
9       9
10      a
11      b
...
34      y
35      z
36      10
37      11
..
45      19
46      1a
...
1295    zz
1296    100
1297    101
```

Comment: I fully expect that you'd be satisfied with @DerVO answer, but if you really needed to preserve the character order abc..xyz012..789 , then you could transpose to it after the base_convert using strtr()... strtr(base_convert($number_dec, 10 , 36), (implode("",range("0","9"))).(implode("",range("a","z"))), (implode("",range("a","z"))).(implode("",range("0","9"))) );'

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dechex` to convert the number to hex

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

For example:

```
1000000 => f4240
1000001 => f4241
1000002 => f4242
1000003 => f4243
1000004 => f4244
1000005 => f4245
1000006 => f4246
1000007 => f4247
1000008 => f4248
1000009 => f4249
1000010 => f424a
1000011 => f424b
1000012 => f424c
1000013 => f424d
1000014 => f424e
1000015 => f424f
1000016 => f4250
1000017 => f4251
1000018 => f4252
1000019 => f4253
1000020 => f4254
```

To convert back, just use `hexdec`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Answer (score 0):

`base64_encode();`

and for decode use

```
base64_decode();
```

Comment: Nooo! By this way the string is longer, not shorter. base64 is for all characters, not for number.

Comment: @fusion3k is completely right - this is not a numerical conversion from base 10 to 64!

Answer (score 0):

Both dechex() and base_convert() will fail with large numbers. They are limited by the maximum size and precision of int and float types internally used during conversion.

The http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base-convert.php discussion has some nice helper functions (see [2](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base-convert.php#106546), [3](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base-convert.php#109660)) that can avoid this problem by using BC-functions to do the math. The BC extension can deal with arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: True - if the user needs to be able to handle massive numbers, this may become an issue. But in that case you could probably find a user defined function on stackoverflow that deals with larger numbers.